# Passing variable up from Child to parent using props and UseState get empty value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I was trying to pass each_daterange to its parent by the code below using props. I have created a useState hook in the parent to retrieve to the change of each_daterange in the drag-down menu and save it to myVar. However, when I console.log(myVar) in parent, I got empty string where I expect it to be a certain date range string like "2020/07/20 - 2020/07/27" when I change the drag down option. Does anyone know the problem?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { WeeklyTrafficCardContainer } from './WeeklyTrafficCard';
import moment from 'moment';

const WeeklyTrafficCard = (props) => {
  var today = moment();
  const dateArray = [];
  var numberOfweeks = 0; //representing how many weeks back
  while (numberOfweeks < 10) {
    var from_date = today.startOf('week').format('MM/DD/YY');
    var to_date = today.endOf('week').format('MM/DD/YY');
    var range = from_date.concat(' ','-',' ',to_date);
    dateArray.push(range);
    today = today.subtract(7, 'days');
    numberOfweeks++;
    //console.log(dateArray);
  }
  const { start, end, data, store, setMyVar} = props;
  const capacity = store && store.capacity;

  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document && document.querySelector('#weekly-traffic-chart');
    if (!element) {
      return;
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (   
   <div className="weekly">
        <div className="weekly-head p-4 text-center">
          <select className="py-2 px-3">
            {dateArray.map(each_daterange => (
                <option key={each_daterange} value={each_daterange} onChange={each_daterange=>setMyVar(each_daterange)}>
                  {each_daterange}
                </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
)
}

export {
  WeeklyTrafficCard
}
```

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { WeeklyTrafficCard } from './WeeklyTrafficCard';
import { AppContext } from 'contexts/App';
import { API_URL } from 'constants/index.js';
import { todayOpen, todayClose } from 'helpers';
import moment from 'moment';

const WeeklyTrafficCardContainer = (props) => {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState('');
  return (
      <div>
        <WeeklyTrafficCard {...props} data={data} setMyVar={setMyVar}/>
        <div>{console.log(myVar)}</div>
      </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two bugs in your JSX:
1.`onChange()` should be an attribute of `select` tag, not of `option`;
2.try changing its value to `onChange={() => setMyVar(this.value)}`

Comment: You'd need `onChange` to call the method on change, not on render, e.g., `onChange={() => setMyVar(this.value)}` (or whatever it'd be).

Comment: Hi, my onChange response on each_daterange, but if I'd put onChange on select tag, it wouldn't see each_daterange declared, because it's declared in option after select

Comment: Doesn't matter, it should recognize selected option with a `value` attribute.

Comment: you mean add a value attribute in select tag and let it be value={each_daterange}?

Comment: No, I mean it's good as it is. Just try my function and tell us what happened :)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the selected value as a props and update the state when the value changes The change event is triggered on the  element, not the  element.

You can access the selected value by `event.target.value`.
So, in `WeeklyTrafficCard`

```
 <select className="py-2 px-3" onChange={(event)=>setMyVar(event.target.value)}>
            {dateArray.map(each_daterange => (
                <option key={each_daterange} value={each_daterange} >
                  {each_daterange}
                </option>
            ))}
          </select>
```